# Problems with changing the date scale on an axis - ggplot

Tags: r

I have the following

```
data.frame
date     ratio
 1992-1    0.5
 1992-1    0.6
 1992-1    0.5
 1992-2    0.7
 1992-2    0.65
 1992-2    0.65
```

and I try to run the following code to create a graph

```
occratiocomb <- ggplot() +
  # blue plot
  geom_line(data=SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL, aes(x=Date, y=ratio_1occ_comb, group = 1, colour="very low")) + 
  geom_smooth(data=SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL, aes(x=Date, y=ratio_1occ_comb), method = loess, fill="red",
              colour="red", size=1) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))


# PROBLEM
occratiocomb + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")
print(occratiocomb)
```

The x axis (date) of my graph is looking terrible since I have monthly data as well as it shows a period of 30 years. The thing I try to do now is to change the date scale from a scale based on months to one based on years. Unfortunately, if I try to run the code the error date_trans works with objects of class Date only, is displayed. In my opinion, this is weird because my date column is already in a date format. Or is the issue related to the fact that my date variable does not contain any days?

Many thanks in advance
Xx
Freddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be due to the format of your date column (as you suspected); if you change the format using e.g. lubridate the breaks work as expected:

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL <- tibble::tribble(
   ~date, ~ratio,
   "1990-1",    "0.5",
   "1990-2",    "0.6",
   "1990-3",    "0.5",
   "1991-1",    "0.7",
  "1991-2",    "0.65",
  "1991-3",    "0.65"
  )
SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL$date <- lubridate::ym(SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL$date)

occratiocomb <- ggplot(SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL, aes(x = date, y=ratio, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", fill = "red", colour = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 month",
               date_breaks = "1 year",
               date_labels = "%Y-%m")
print(occratiocomb)
```

[image: example.png]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. As I try to run the lubridate code, the error message "ym is not an exported object of 'namespace:lubridate'" .  Do you have any idea what could be the issue regarding that?

Comment: It might have to do with the version of lubridate you have installed - this code works with version 1.7.9.2 - if possible, please edit your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: An alternative is to use the zoo package (`install.packages("zoo")`) and replace the line `SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL$date <- lubridate::ym(SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL$date)` with `SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL$date <- zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(SKILL_1_OCC_FINAL$date))`